# Sonar cube issue on filter

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

**The return value of "filter" must be used.** - got this error message during build during sonar cube quality.

```
this.item.filter(function (e) {
    if (e.id == 1026) {
        e.code ='Add Network';
    }
});
```

Comment: First big question - why use `filter`? You're just doing basic iteration - use `forEach` or a regular loop.

Comment: It seems like you want to apply an in-place transformation to each element of an iterable. Use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead.

Comment: that is in search function, need it on the go

Comment: So, you *need* to filter the array to a subset of it but without ever returning `true` or `false` which is *how filtering works*, therefore you always filter down to an empty array? And it's also imperative that you mutate the array while you're filtering it to nothing? And you never use that nothing anyway? And this *cannot* be done by any other iteration mechanism even though you're just doing simple iteration without in any way shape or form approaching it like filtering? I'm not sure you've answered how `filter` makes any sense here.